# getting this error 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_balance_f' on my rest api

Tags: python, api

Im making a rest api so I can communicate with my python script that does requests to a website and gets the data from the website.

```
class Classroom():
    def __init__(self, numbercard, password) -> None:
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.school = 400786
        self.numbercard = numbercard
        self.password = password
        self.logged_in = False


        def login(self):
        payload = {
            'modo': 'manual',
            'escola': '400786',
            'nrcartao': self.numbercard,
            'codigo': self.password,
        }

        res = self.session.post('http://giae.esars.pt/cgi-bin/webgiae2.exe/loginv2', 
        json=payload)

        self.logged_in = res.ok

        def get_balance_f(self):
        balance_request = self.session.get('http://giae.esars.pt/cgi- 
        bin/webgiae2.exe/saldo')
        balance_json = balance_request.json()

        
        self.balance = balance_json['saldo']
        
        print(balance_json['saldo'])
```

this is one part of my python scrip that logins into the website and gets how much money i have in my school card.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from classroom import Classroom
from random import choice

chars = [
'q',
'w',
'e',
'r',
't',
'y',
'u',
'i',
'o',
'p',
'a',
's',
'd',
'f',
'g',
'h',
'j',
'k',
]

app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_id() -> str:
    return ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(8))

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login_receive():
    card_number = request.json['username']
    password = request.json['password']
    user = Classroom(card_number, password)
    user.login()
    if user.logged_in:
        uid = generate_id()

        return {'message': 'Login succesful', 'uid':uid}
    else:
        return {'message': 'Login failed'}
    

    @app.route('/classroom/myinfo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def myinfo():
    user = request.headers['uid']

    return user.get_balance_f()
```

on this code the login part is working, but when i tried to send a get request i get this error 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_balance_f', and i dont get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `myinfo()` function you define the variable `user` as the `uid` header's value. Then, you call the `get_balance_f()` method on that user variable, which is most likely just a string — there is no function defined on the default python string object with that name.

You declared the `user` variable inside your `login_receive()` function as  `user = Classroom(card_number, password)`. This would work, but, as you're defining the variable inside that function, its' scope is limited to that function only. I see you tried to indent the `myinfo()` function to supposedly inherit the scope from the `login_receive()` function, but that won't work as you're defining different routes.

Maybe try instantiating your `Classroom` class as a global variable (outside a function) and then call its' methods inside the functions, as it has global scope.

[...]

```
my_classroom = Classroom()

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login_receive():
    card_number = request.json['username']
    password = request.json['password']
    user = my_classroom(card_number, password)
    user.login()
    if user.logged_in:
        uid = generate_id()

        return {'message': 'Login succesful', 'uid':uid}
    else:
        return {'message': 'Login failed'}
    

@app.route('/classroom/myinfo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def myinfo():
    user = request.headers['uid']

    return my_classroom.get_balance_f()
```

(with this indentation)

Also, try not to use such a simple token generation method for session purposes. Even if you're just using it in a private environment, it's always worth it to implement proper security in your apps.

PS: Pretty nice that you're messing around with GIAE's API! There's a lot of information on there which you can use for automating stuff and creating nice apps to improve your school experience. If you need any more help with GIAE's API just let me know!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you want to contribute in Portuguese, please do so on the dedicated [pt.so] site.

Comment: PS: It would be nice to talk a little bit more about my project with you!!!

Comment: @TiagoAfonso I'd love to! How would you want me to reach you?

Comment: @jonasmylesx do you have discord or twitter?

Comment: @TiagoAfonso hey, sorry for the huge delay, been busy. If you’re still interested in this please let me know!

Comment: @jonasmylesx hey, no problem i have been quite busy lately, im would like to talk more about the project with you, whats the best way i can reach you?

Comment: @TiagoAfonso are you on discord?

Comment: @jonasmylesx yes heres my tag Squid#4544